# CORS: preflight passes, main request completes w/200, but browser still has Origin error

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, express, cors

I am sending a CORS ajax request to a node server running express.  In both the server logs and the js console, I can see that the preflight OPTIONS request succeeds.

Then, the main request also succeeds on the server and responds with a 200 and what I think are the correct headers.  However, in Chrome, the networking tab reports the latter request as "cancelled" and the response is not accepted or processed:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myserver.com/upload. Origin http://mysite.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Here are the server logs with the headers printed out for both requests and responses:

```
76.79.201.210 - - [27/Jun/2013:23:23:17 +0000] "OPTIONS /upload HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "http://mysite.com/add" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36"
START
{ host: 'localhost:5001',
  connection: 'close',
  'content-length': '109587',
  origin: 'http://mysite.com',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36',
  'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryBZA4TATeeVWMHArH',
  accept: '*/*',
  referer: 'http://mysite.com/add',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8' }
{ 'x-powered-by': 'Express',
  'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
  'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
  'access-control-allow-headers': 'X-Requested-With' }
XX.XX.XXX.210 - - [27/Jun/2013:23:23:19 +0000] "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 200 118 "http://mysite.com/add" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36"
- - - [Thu, 27 Jun 2013 23:23:19 GMT] "POST /upload HTTP/1.0" 200 - "http://mysite.com/add" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36"
```

Update:  screenshot from Chrome's network tab -- the "cancelled" one is the one that was a 200 above

http://cl.ly/image/3c09330i1a17

Comment: I've also tried setting "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" to "*" with the same result

Comment: You are setting the CORS headers on the actual request too right? not just the preflight?

Comment: Yes, the second set of headers (starting with x-powered-by) above are the ones for the main response.  I didn't print out the options request headers, but they are the same.

Comment: I had the same problem with a Spring Boot server and a different solution for it. (I know the question is old) For me it was because I used an `expired access token` in my request. Instead of access denied I got a 200 in the preflight and and a CORS error with missing Access Allowed Headers. After using a valid baerer token it worked.

Comment: Screenshot link doesn't work. Could you also log both CORS request/response headers and then main response request/response headers as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that because I had both nginx and express set up to respond with headers to the options request, it was somehow combining the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header value into "*", "*".  I don't know if it read that as an array or what.

Still pretty baffled because 1) Why did the request make it past nginx? and 2) Why did the browser proceed with the POST if the OPTIONS headers were messed up?

Oh well, the lesson, as always -- Don't Repeat Yourself.

Comment: There is a bug in... Chrome maybe(?) that will proceed with the post regardless of the results of the OPTIONS.  I was getting 405s on it and still passing through to the POST.  Getting it to work correctly is *hard*, apparently!

Answer (score 6):

> **Troubleshooting CORS-Related Problems**
>
> - If you are trying to reproduce the problem, and you're not seeing a request/response, **it is possible that your browser has cached an earlier failed preflight request attempt**. Clearing your browser's cache may also clear the preflight cache...
>
> https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin

I tested the following configuration on [test-cors.org](https://www.test-cors.org/) and it appears to work. Just remember to clear your cache every now and then while you are troubleshooting.

```
var allowedHost = {
    // this is the origin that test-cors.org uses
    'http://client.cors-api.appspot.com': true
};

var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.headers.origin || allowedHost[req.headers.origin]) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin)
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version');
        if (req.method == 'OPTIONS') res.send(200);
        else next();
    }
    else {
        res.send(403, {
            auth: false
        });
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: This log, and that "localhost", are actually on the server itself, which has its own domain, so Chrome is actually talking to myserver.com/upload, not localhost:5001/upload

Comment: Thanks - Still no luck, though, or with Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *

Comment: Thanks for the information on caching of preflights.

Comment: Also...  you can add the `Cache-Control: no-cache` header in the request

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, spent quite some time debugging...

I configured/debugged CORS server (nextjs app) reply, it was replying with 200 ok pre-flight OPTIONS, cleared browser (Chrome) cache nothing helped until I simply switched from using JS code like "const response = await fetch(" to "let res = axios.post(".

My issue was something to be with the client side library I was using in my RectJS app and the way it was making/handling HTTP/CORS.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35511384)