# sailsjs cors bad request still getting through to controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors, sails.js

So my cors.js file looks like

```
module.exports.cors = {
  allRoutes: true,
  origin: require('./local.js').hosts, // this is 'http://localhost'
}
```

I then chose a random site to make a request from, in this case: http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/

Here is my request and response from the page

> $.post('http://localhost:1337/gift/create') Object {readyState: 1,
>   getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function,
>   setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
>   jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:1337/gift/create 
>   (index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:1337/gift/create. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header contains the invalid value ''. Origin
>   'http://tools.pingdom.com' is therefore not allowed access.

However, I'm still getting errors in the console as the controller function still gets called.

```
sails> error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response: 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
```

I would think that cors should just end the connection if it fails.

Am I missing a setting?

This is a duplicate of this post [CORS: preflight passes, main request completes w/200, but browser still has Origin error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355020/cors-preflight-passes-main-request-completes-w-200-but-browser-still-has-orig) but it does not seem like it was resolved.  Do we know why the post continues to go through?

Here is the response header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:2
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 28 Jan 2015 15:56:51 GMT
Set-Cookie:sails.sid=s%3A5TJr82PCN-Tas2GrfKkhooEB.IWwc75iQUPRYoR7qWSep6xc%2BSLUkOV0IQe0w63GDYrQ; Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By:Sails <sailsjs.org>
```

There is not access-control-allow-origin set. I can make a policy for that, but is this is bug in Sails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things first: you should never be getting that 500 error, because you should be validating those fields in your controller code before using them!

As for the request still being processed despite your CORS settings: what you're seeing is the intended behavior, but I empathize with your confusion.  Here's what you have to understand about CORS and POST requests:

*POST requests don't trigger a preflight request from the browser as long as they use a common content type header like `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`*.

The reason for this is that it has long been the case that regular old HTML forms are allowed to freely POST to a different origin.  When you do a regular jQuery `$.post`, it uses that same content type, so the server can't distinguish it from a regular form POST and lets it through.  The *browser*, upon receiving the empty `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, says "no way Jose" and refuses to show the response, but by that time the ship has sailed--that POST request has been processed.

If you don't want *any* requests from non-whitelisted origins to be processed by Sails, you can set the `securityLevel` in your CORS config to `1` (high) or `2` (very high):

```
module.exports.cors = {
  allRoutes: true,
  origin: require('./local.js').hosts, // this is 'http://localhost',
  securityLevel: 1
}
```

This will cause Sails to return a 403 response to any request from a disallowed domain.  The difference between `high` and `very high` is that `high` will still allow cross-origin requests from different protocols (so your [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) requests will still work), whereas `very high` locks everything down tight.

Comment: Would you mind explaining it a bit more? What does that header have to do with Sails' decision to process all requests regardless of origin by default?

Comment: I wouldn't characterize this as a decision by Sails; this is what any web server would do.  The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is something _sent_ by the server to instruct the client what it should do with the response.  Non-browser clients will typically ignore the header, but standards-compliant browsers will take an empty `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to mean, "I should not have access to this response" and refuse to make it available to client-side scripts.